# how do I write SSH command output with only values I need

Tags: ssh, command, output

I am creating a VPS with the API provided for command line. The output of the command comes with several text inside which I don't need. This is my command.

*The variables are predefined and work fine.*

```
echo y | /usr/local/bin/CLICMD vm create --hostname=$VMNAME --domain=$srvdomain --cpu 1 --memory 1024 --image $image --datacenter=$dc --billing=hourly -n 100 > /dev/null 1>> /home/logs/createvps.log
```

When I run it, it gives me the following output in createvps.log file,

> This action will incur charges on your account. Continue? [y/N]: id       11232312
>   created  2015-06-13T14:43:27-05:00
>   guid     xxxxxx-r345-4323-8e3f-c8c04e18fad7

From the above output, I just need to have id (11232312) value stored in a mysql table. I know how to grab the value from log file and save in mysql.

My question is, how do I save just that id in the log file instead of all the other values/strings.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is exactly your question, but I guess this should help you:

```
echo y | /usr/local/bin/CLICMD vm create --hostname=$VMNAME \
 --domain=$srvdomain --cpu 1 --memory 1024 --image $image \
 --datacenter=$dc --billing=hourly -n 100 | \
 grep -oE "id [0-9]+$" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+" >> /home/logs/createvps.log
```

Few notes to difference in your code and mine:

- You do two redirection of stdout, one to /dev/null and one to your log, which is equivalent of doing just one redirection (writing in /dev/null is practically NOP).

Comment: Thanks for trying. Unfortunately the log file created blank with no output in it. However the command worked fine and created the VPS accordingly. To clarify the question, I just need to save the VPS id which comes in the result output by the server after creating the VPS. thanks

Comment: you can try without the $ in the end or experiment little bit. Just tested and for your example code it works for me (at least on Linux).

Comment: I tried. but no luck. let me do some more experiments. thanks for your help.

Comment: I found out the problem. It was a long space in output where it says id and then the id number. it has a long space in between. I added the same space in grep and it worked. Thank you so much. The actual command which worked for me is `| grep -Eo "id       [0-9]+"`